# Discord.py Task Loop Running Too Often and Not Completing

Tags: python, concurrency, discord.py, task, python-asyncio

I'm currently running into an issue with Discord.py where I have a task loop which keeps reiterating instantly without actually finishing. Below you can find a snippet of my code.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import utils

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is Ready.")
    my_task.start()

@tasks.loop(minutes=5)
async def my_task():
    print("Starting my_task")
    output = utils.generate_output()
    print(output)
```

Whenever I run my code, the output is as follows :

```
Bot is ready.
Starting my_task
Starting my_task
Starting my_task
Starting my_task
Starting my_task
Starting my_task
```

It sends "Starting my_task" roughly every second or two, and keeps on doing that until I exit the program. The function generate_output() never seems to complete, and I never get to the print(output) statement before the task seems to just restart.

For some context, generate_output() is a function which returns a list of sources from a news page. The function scrapes the webpage using BeautifulSoup and manipulates some data using a Pandas Dataframe, then writes it to a local file before returning a list.

my_task() runs perfectly on its own, but as soon as I want to put it into the Discord.py task loop, it never seems to execute.

I feel as though I've got some form of concurrency or task error happening within the function, though I don't know how or why, and I'm at my wits end. I can get other tasks working just fine, but as soon as I add this one to the mix, it all breaks, and all of my tasks start behaving like this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix my issue.

It was happening as a byproduct of the `f = open("filepath", "w")` within my `utils.generate_output()` function. I had a relative path for my file path, not a direct path. I guess the way open() handles those is different, and as a result my program was bugging out.

I hope those who stumble upon this get saved the headache.

Answer (score 0):

Little more explanations for those having the same problem, like I had:

When your loop task raises an exception, discord.py's `Loop` helper class might handle it. If it is an instance of one of `Loop._valid_exception`, (including `OSError`,) the library will handle it silently and will run the task few seconds later. (For the details of the logic, you can [search the repository for `_valid_exception`](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3ARapptz%2Fdiscord.py%20_valid_exception&type=code).)

You can debug your task with something like this:

```py
@tasks.loop(minutes=5)
async def your_buggy_task():
    try:
        await your_buggy_function()
    except Exception as e:
        import traceback
        traceback.print_exception(e)
        raise e  # If you want discord.py to retry the task few seconds later
        1/0  # If you want to stop this task to be run again
```